# Residual plots of a regression model in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, statistics, regression

I'm trying to transform two residual plots performed below into `ggplot2`.
As a description, in order to perform these graphs, it is necessary to previously define some functions associated with the specifics of the class of the adopted model, which I am providing below.
The model is in the `fit` argument whose data is from the `nlme` library, and the graphs are plotted at the end of the code using the `qqPlot2` function.

```
rm(list = ls()); cat('\014')

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)
library(gamlss)
library(gridExtra)
library(hnp)
library(car)

extract.lmeDesign2 <- function(m){
  start.level = 1
  data <- getData(m)
  grps <- nlme::getGroups(m)
  n <- length(grps)
  X <- list()
  grp.dims <- m$dims$ncol
  Zt <- model.matrix(m$modelStruct$reStruct, data)
  cov <- as.matrix(m$modelStruct$reStruct)
  i.col <- 1
  n.levels <- length(m$groups)
  Z <- matrix(0, n, 0)
  if (start.level <= n.levels) {
    for (i in 1:(n.levels - start.level + 1)) {
      if (length(levels(m$groups[[n.levels - i + 1]])) != 1)
      {
        X[[1]] <- model.matrix(~m$groups[[n.levels - i +
                                            1]] - 1, 
                               contrasts.arg = c("contr.treatment",
                                                 "contr.treatment"))
      }
      else X[[1]] <- matrix(1, n, 1)
      X[[2]] <- as.matrix(Zt[, i.col:(i.col + grp.dims[i] -
                                        1)])
      i.col <- i.col + grp.dims[i]
      Z <- cbind(mgcv::tensor.prod.model.matrix(X),Z)
    }
    Vr <- matrix(0, ncol(Z), ncol(Z))
    start <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n.levels - start.level + 1)) {
      k <- n.levels - i + 1
      for (j in 1:m$dims$ngrps[i]) {
        stop <- start + ncol(cov[[k]]) - 1
        Vr[ncol(Z) + 1 - (stop:start),ncol(Z) + 1 - (stop:start)] <- cov[[k]]
        start <- stop + 1
      }
    }
  }
  X <- if (class(m$call$fixed) == "name" &&  !is.null(m$data$X)) {
    m$data$X
  } else   {
    model.matrix(formula(eval(m$call$fixed)),data)
  }
  y <- as.vector(matrix(m$residuals, ncol = NCOL(m$residuals))[,NCOL(m$residuals)] + 
                   matrix(m$fitted, ncol = NCOL(m$fitted))[,NCOL(m$fitted)])
  return(list(
    Vr = Vr,                                                                 
    X = X,
    Z = Z,
    sigmasq = m$sigma ^ 2,
    lambda = unique(diag(Vr)),
    y = y,
    k = n.levels
  )
  )
}
fit = lme(distance ~ age, method="REML",data = Orthodont)
data.fit <- extract.lmeDesign2(fit)
data <-    getData(fit)
y <- data.fit$y
X <- data.fit$X
N <- length(y)                                                               
id <-  sort(as.numeric(getGroups(fit, level = 1)), index.return = TRUE)$x   
n <- length(as.numeric(names(table(id))))                                    
vecni <- (table(id))                                                         
p <- ncol(X)                                                                
n.levels <- length(fit$groups)                                               
start.level <- 1
Cgrps <- nlme::getGroups(fit, level = start.level)                           
CCind <- levels((Cgrps))                                                     
sigma2 <- fit$sigma^2
obs <- numeric()

for (i in 1:n)
{
  obs <- append(obs,1:vecni[i])                                               
}
if (n.levels > 1) { 
  lZi <- list()
  lgi <- list()
  numrow <- numeric()
  
  mgroups <- fit$groups      
  for (n in 1:length(CCind)) {
    dgi <- data.frame(as.matrix(mgroups[mgroups == CCind[n], ]))
    nrowzi <- dim(dgi)[1]
    ncolzi <- 0
    girep <- as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,1])))
    for (k in 2:n.levels) {
      girep <- c(girep,as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,k]))))
    }
    for (k in 1:n.levels) {
      ncolzi <- ncolzi + as.numeric(length(levels(dgi[,k])))
    }
    auxi <- as.vector(table(dgi[,1]))
    for (i in 2:n.levels) {
      auxi <- c(auxi,as.vector(table(dgi[,i])))
    }
    l <- 1
    Zi <- matrix(0,nrowzi,ncolzi)
    for (j in 1:ncolzi) {
      Zi[l:(l + auxi[j] - 1),j] <- rep(1,auxi[j]) 
      l <- l + auxi[j]
      if (l == (nrowzi + 1)) l <- 1
    }
    
    lZi[[n]] <- Zi
    
    numrow[n] <- dim(Zi)[1]
    
    comp.var <- as.matrix(fit1$modelStruct$reStruct)
    auxg <- rep(as.numeric(comp.var[1])*sigma2,girep[1])
    for (i in 2:length(girep)) {
      auxg <- c(auxg,rep(as.numeric(comp.var[i])*sigma2,girep[i]))
    }
    lgi[[n]] <- diag(auxg)
  }
  q <- dim(lgi[[1]])[1]                     
  for (h in 2:length(CCind)) {
    q <- c(q,dim(lgi[[h]])[1])
  }
  Z <- lZi[[1]]
  for (k in 2:length(CCind)) {
    Z <- bdiag(Z,(lZi[[k]]))
  }
  Z <- as.matrix(Z)
  nrowZi <- lZi[[1]]                        
  for (h in 2:length(CCind)) {
    nrowZi <- c(nrowZi,dim(lZi[[h]])[1])
  }
  
  Gam <- lgi[[1]]
  for (k in 2:length(CCind)) {
    Gam <- bdiag(Gam,(lgi[[k]]))
  }
  Gam <- as.matrix(Gam)
}else{
  mataux <- model.matrix(fit$modelStruct$reStruct,data)
  mataux <- as.data.frame(cbind(mataux,id))
  lZi <- list()
  lgi <- list()
  
  for (i in (as.numeric(unique(id)))) { 
    lZi[[i]] <- as.matrix((subset(split(mataux,id == i,
                                        drop = T)$`TRUE`,select = -id)))          
    lgi[[i]] <- getVarCov(fit,type = "random.effects")
  }
  Z <- as.matrix(bdiag(lZi))
  g <- getVarCov(fit,type = "random.effects")
  q <- dim(g)[1]                                                           
  Gam <- as.matrix(kronecker(diag(length(as.numeric(unique(id)))),g))
}
if (n.levels > 1) {   
  if (!inherits(fit, "lme")) 
    stop("object does not appear to be of class lme")
  grps <- nlme::getGroups(fit)
  n <- length(grps)                                                                     
  n.levels <- length(fit$groups)                                                         
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)) 
    n.corlevels <- 0
  else n.corlevels <- length(all.vars(nlme::getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct))) 
  if (n.levels < n.corlevels) {
    getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)
    vnames <- all.vars(nlme::getGroupsFormula(fit$modelStruct$corStruct))
    lab <- paste(eval(parse(text = vnames[1]), envir = fit$data))
    if (length(vnames) > 1) 
      for (i in 2:length(vnames)) {
        lab <- paste(lab, "/", eval(parse(text = vnames[i]), 
                                    envir = fit$data), sep = "")
      }
    grps <- factor(lab)
  }
  if (n.levels >= start.level || n.corlevels >= start.level) {
    if (n.levels >= start.level) 
      Cgrps <- nlme::getGroups(fit, level = start.level)                          
    else Cgrps <- grps
    Cind <- sort(as.numeric(Cgrps), index.return = TRUE)$ix                       
    rCind <- 1:n 
    rCind[Cind] <- 1:n
    Clevel <- levels(Cgrps)                                                      
    n.cg <- length(Clevel)                                                         
    size.cg <- array(0, n.cg)
    for (i in 1:n.cg) size.cg[i] <- sum(Cgrps == Clevel[i])  
}
  else {
    n.cg <- 1
    Cind <- 1:n
  }
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$varStruct)) 
    w <- rep(fit$sigma, n)
  else {
    w <- 1/nlme::varWeights(fit$modelStruct$varStruct)
    group.name <- names(fit$groups)
    order.txt <- paste("ind<-order(data[[\"", group.name[1], 
                       "\"]]", sep = "")
    if (length(fit$groups) > 1) 
      for (i in 2:length(fit$groups)) order.txt <- paste(order.txt, 
                       ",data[[\"", group.name[i], "\"]]", sep = "")
    order.txt <- paste(order.txt, ")")
    eval(parse(text = order.txt))
    w[ind] <- w
    w <- w * fit$sigma
  }
  w <- w[Cind]
  if (is.null(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)) 
    lR <- array(1, n)
  else {
    c.m <- nlme::corMatrix(fit$modelStruct$corStruct)
    if (!is.list(c.m)) {
      lR <- c.m
      lR <- lR[Cind, ]
      lR <- lR[, Cind]
    }
    else {
      lR <- list()
      ind <- list()
      for (i in 1:n.cg) {
        lR[[i]] <- matrix(0, size.cg[i], size.cg[i])
        ind[[i]] <- 1:size.cg[i]
      }
      Roff <- cumsum(c(1, size.cg))
      gr.name <- names(c.m)
      n.g <- length(c.m)
      j0 <- rep(1, n.cg)
      ii <- 1:n
      for (i in 1:n.g) {
        Clev <- unique(Cgrps[grps == gr.name[i]])
        if (length(Clev) > 1) 
          stop("inner groupings not nested in outer!!")
        k <- (1:n.cg)[Clevel == Clev]
        j1 <- j0[k] + nrow(c.m[[i]]) - 1
        lR[[k]][j0[k]:j1, j0[k]:j1] <- c.m[[i]]
        ind1 <- ii[grps == gr.name[i]]
        ind2 <- rCind[ind1]
        ind[[k]][j0[k]:j1] <- ind2 - Roff[k] + 1
        j0[k] <- j1 + 1
      }
      for (k in 1:n.cg) {
        lR[[k]][ind[[k]], ] <- lR[[k]]
        lR[[k]][, ind[[k]]] <- lR[[k]]
      }
    }
  }
  if (is.list(lR)) {
    for (i in 1:n.cg) {
      wi <- w[Roff[i]:(Roff[i] + size.cg[i] - 1)]
      lR[[i]] <- as.vector(wi) * t(as.vector(wi) * lR[[i]]) 
    }
  }
  else if (is.matrix(lR)) {
    lR <- as.vector(w) * t(as.vector(w) * lR)
  }
  else {
    lR <- w^2 * lR
  }
  if (is.list(lR)) {
    R <- lR[[1]]
    for (k in 2:n.cg) {
      R <- bdiag(R,lR[[k]])
    }
    R <- as.matrix(R)
  }
  else{
    R <- diag(lR)
  }
}else{
  R <- getVarCov(fit,type = "conditional",individual = 1)[[1]]
  for (i in 2:length(as.numeric(unique(id)))) {
    R <- as.matrix(bdiag(R,getVarCov(fit,
                                     type = "conditional",individual = i)[[1]] ) )
  }
}
sqrt.matrix <- function(mat) {              
  mat <- as.matrix(mat)  
  singular_dec <- svd(mat,LINPACK = F)
  U <- singular_dec$u
  V <- singular_dec$v
  D <- diag(singular_dec$d)
  sqrtmatrix <- U %*% sqrt(D) %*% t(V)
}
V <- (Z %*% Gam %*% t(Z)) + R
iV <- solve(V)                                                
varbeta <- solve((t(X) %*% iV %*% X))
Q <- (iV - iV %*% X %*% (varbeta) %*% t(X) %*% iV ) 
zq <- t(Z) %*% Q
norm.frob.ZtQ <- sum(diag(zq %*% t(zq)))
eblue <- as.vector(fixef(fit))
eblup <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% iV %*% (y - X %*% eblue)
predm <- X %*% eblue                       
predi <- X %*% eblue + Z %*% eblup         
resm <- (y - predm)                        
resc <- (y - predi)  
var.resm <- V - X %*% solve(t(X) %*% iV %*% X) %*% t(X) 
var.resc <- R %*% Q %*% R
ident <- diag(N)
auxnum <- (R %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% R)
auxden <- R %*% Q %*% R
CF <- diag(auxnum)/diag(auxden)
rescp <- resc/sqrt(diag(var.resc))
R.half <- sqrt.matrix(R)
auxqn <- eigen((R.half %*% Q %*% R.half), symmetric = T, only.values = FALSE) 
lt <- sqrt(solve(diag((auxqn$values[1:(N-p)])))) %*% t(auxqn$vectors[1:N,1:(N-p)]) %*% solve(sqrt.matrix(R[1:N,1:N]))
var.resmcp <- lt %*% var.resc[1:N,1:N] %*% t(lt)
resmcp <- (lt %*% resc[1:N] )/sqrt(diag(var.resmcp))
 if (n.levels > 1) {
    aux <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam
    qm <- q - 1
    dm <- matrix(0,length(CCind),1)
    gbi <- aux[1:(q[1]),(1:q[1])]
    eblupi <- eblup[1:(q[1]),]
    dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
    dm[1] <- dmi
    for (j in 2:length(CCind)) {
      gbi <- aux[((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)]),((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)])]
      eblupi <- eblup[((j - 1)*q[(j - 1)] + 1 ):(q[j] + q[(j - 1)]),]
      dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
      dm[j] <- dmi
    }
  }else{
    aux <- Gam %*% t(Z) %*% Q %*% Z %*% Gam
    qm <- q - 1
    dm <- matrix(0,n,1)
    
    for (j in 1:length(CCind)) 
    {
      if (q == 1)
      {
        gbi <- aux[j,j]
        eblupi <- eblup[(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
        dm[j] <- dmi
      }
      else
      {
        gbi <- aux[(q*j - qm):(q*j),(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        cat(gbi,'\n','\t')
        eblupi <- eblup[(q*j - qm):(q*j)]
        dmi <- t(eblupi) %*% ginv(gbi) %*% eblupi
        dm[j] <- dmi
      }
    }
    
  }
qqPlot2 <- function(x, distribution="norm", ..., ylab=deparse(substitute(x)),
                    xlab=paste(distribution, "quantiles"), main = NULL, 
                    las = par("las"),
                    envelope = .95,  
                    col = palette()[1], 
                    col.lines = palette()[2], lwd = 2, pch = 1, cex = par("cex"),
                    cex.lab = par("cex.lab"), cex.axis = par("cex.axis"), 
                    line = c("quartiles", "robust", "none"), 
                    labels = if (!is.null(names(x))) names(x) else seq(along = x),
                    id.method = "y", 
                    id.n = if (id.method[1] == "identify") Inf else 0,
                    id.cex = 1, id.col=palette()[1], grid = TRUE)
{
  line <- match.arg(line)
  good <- !is.na(x)
  ord <- order(x[good])
  ord.x <- x[good][ord]
  ord.lab <- labels[good][ord]
  q.function <- eval(parse(text = paste("q", distribution, sep = "")))
  d.function <- eval(parse(text = paste("d", distribution, sep = "")))
  n <- length(ord.x)
  P <- ppoints(n)
  z <- q.function(P, ...)
  plot(z, ord.x, type = "n", xlab = xlab, 
ylab = ylab, main = main, 
las = las,cex.lab = cex.lab, cex.axis = cex.axis)
  if (grid) {
    grid(lty = 1, equilogs = FALSE)
    box()}
  points(z, ord.x, col = col, pch = pch, cex = cex)
  if (line  == "quartiles" || line == "none") {
    Q.x <- quantile(ord.x, c(.25,.75))
    Q.z <- q.function(c(.25,.75), ...)
    b <- (Q.x[2] - Q.x[1])/(Q.z[2] - Q.z[1])
    a <- Q.x[1] - b*Q.z[1]
    abline(a, b, col = col.lines, lwd = lwd)
  }
  if (line == "robust") {
    coef <- coef(rlm(ord.x ~ z))
    a <- coef[1]
    b <- coef[2]
    abline(a, b)
  }
  conf <- if (envelope == FALSE) .95 else envelope
  zz <- qnorm(1 - (1 - conf)/2)
  SE <- (b/d.function(z, ...))*sqrt(P*(1 - P)/n)
  fit.value <- a + b*z
  upper <- fit.value + zz*SE
  lower <- fit.value - zz*SE
  if (envelope != FALSE) {
    lines(z, upper, lty = 2, lwd = lwd, col = col.lines)
    lines(z, lower, lty = 2, lwd = lwd, col = col.lines)
  }
}

x11()
qqPlot2(resmcp, ylab = "Resíduos", 
        xlab = "Quantil N(0,1)", pch = 20) 
qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
        ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
        xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

My attempt to reproduce them in `ggplot2` was as follows:

```
P1 = qqPlot2(resmcp, ylab = "Resíduos", 
        xlab = "Quantil N(0,1)", pch = 20)   
PP1 = ggplot(data = P1, aes(resmcp)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = resmcp), show.legend = FALSE)

P2 = qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
        ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
        xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")
PP2 = ggplot(data = P2, aes(dm)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = dm), show.legend = FALSE)
x11()
gridExtra::grid.arrange(PP1,PP2, ncol = 2)
```

However, something is happening, as I have gotten the following result:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

See my attempt below for the quantile mahalanobis distance graph vs. chi-square quantiles:

```
gVals <- function(y, dist, conf){ # distribution; confidence interval
  y <- sort(y) # make sure they're in order
  p <- ppoints(length(y))
  if(dist == "chisq") {
    zi <- qchisq(p, df = length(p) - 1)
    zd <- dchisq(zi, df = length(p) - 1)
    qz <- qchisq(c(.25, .75), length(p) - 1)
  } else {
    zi <- qnorm(p)
    zd <- dnorm(zi)
    qz <- qnorm(c(.25, .75))
  }
  # if quartiles preferred
  qx <- quantile(y, c(.25, .75))
  b <- (qx[2] - qx[1]) / (qz[2] - qz[1])
  a <- qx[1] - b * qz[1]
  
  # if robust preferred  
  # coef <- coef(rlm(y~zi))
  # a <- coef[1]
  # b <- coef[2]
  
  z <- qnorm(1 - (1 - conf)/2)   # z = 1.96 for 95%...
  se <- (b / zd) * sqrt(p * (1 - p)/length(p))
  ft <- a + b * zi 
  uc <- ft + z * se
  dc <- ft - z * se
  dff = data.frame(z = zi, y = y, uc = uc, dc = dc)
  list(a = a, b = b, dff = dff) # returns intercept, slope, and data frame
}

cdf <- gVals(dm, "chisq", .95) # dm is defined in the previous code above
ggplot(cdf$dff, aes(x = z, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = cdf$a[[1]], slope = cdf$b[[1]]) +
  annotate("line", x = cdf$dff$z, y = cdf$dff$uc, color = "red", lty = 2) +
  annotate("line", x = cdf$dff$z, y = cdf$dff$dc, color = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

Note that the x axis should go from 0 to 8, and the y axis should go from 0 to 14. Also, the shape of the simulation envelope is not similar. I am not able to fix this problem.

Comment: Instead of `geom_point`, use `stat_qq` and `stat_qq_line`. For example `ggplot(P1, aes (sample = resmcp)) + stat_qq() + stat_qq_line()`

Comment: Hi @Kat, thanks for the information, but that way the simulation envelope bands are not created. Could you post a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it through the library `qqplotr`.

```
library(qqplotr)
dist <- "chisq"
dpar <- list(df = q)
QT <- data.frame(QUANTIS = dm); ggplot(QT, aes(sample = QUANTIS)) +
  stat_qq_band(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_point(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_line(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar, color = "blue");
qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
             ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
             xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Update

> Instead of having the code for the option `quartile` commented out, I have commented out the code for the option `robust` in the function. Additionally, instead of returning a data frame, it returns a list. FYI, you only need the MASS package if you use the `robust` option (for the function `rlm`).

This function is based on the code used in `qqPlot2` in your question. However, it doesn't return a plot; it returns data.

```
library(car)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
  
gVals <- function(y, dist, conf){ # distribution; confidence interval
  y <- sort(y) # make sure they're in order
  p <- ppoints(length(y))
  if(dist == "chisq") {
    zi <- qchisq(p, df = length(p) - 1)
    zd <- dchisq(zi, df = length(p) - 1)
    qz <- qchisq(c(.25, .75), length(p) - 1)
  } else {
    zi <- qnorm(p)
    zd <- dnorm(zi)
    qz <- qnorm(c(.25, .75))
  }
  # if quartiles preferred
  qx <- quantile(y, c(.25, .75))
  b <- (qx[2] - qx[1]) / (qz[2] - qz[1])
  a <- qx[1] - b * qz[1]
  
  # if robust preferred  
  # coef <- coef(rlm(y~zi))
  # a <- coef[1]
  # b <- coef[2]
  
  z <- qnorm(1 - (1 - conf)/2)   # z = 1.96 for 95%...
  se <- (b / zd) * sqrt(p * (1 - p)/length(p))
  ft <- a + b * zi 
  uc <- ft + z * se
  dc <- ft - z * se
  dff = data.frame(z = zi, y = y, uc = uc, dc = dc)
  list(a = a, b = b, dff = dff) # returns intercept, slope, and data frame
}
```

Here is a comparison with some arbitrary data.

```
data(mtcars)

qqPlot2(mtcars$mpg)
qqPlot2(mtcars$mpg, dist = "chisq", df = 31)

ndf <- gVals(mtcars$mpg, "norm", .95)

ggplot(ndf$dff, aes(x = z, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = ndf$a[[1]], slope = ndf$b[[1]]) +
  annotate("line", x = ndf$dff$z, y = ndf$dff$uc, color = "red", lty = 2) +
  annotate("line", x = ndf$dff$z, y = ndf$dff$dc, color = "red", lty = 2)

cdf <- gVals(mtcars$mpg, "chisq", .95)

ggplot(cdf$dff, aes(x = z, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = cdf$a[[1]], slope = cdf$b[[1]]) +
  annotate("line", x = cdf$dff$z, y = cdf$dff$uc, color = "red", lty = 2) +
  annotate("line", x = cdf$dff$z, y = cdf$dff$dc, color = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kat, thanks for your help, but note that the confidence bands in the second graph (distance from mahalanobis quantile vs. chi-square quantiles) is not similar to the example above. How could I do them in the way presented above?
I've tried in some ways to adapt them, but I'm not succeeding.

Comment: The Mahalanobis distance is a measure within & between observations. There is no  Mahalanobis distance with one variable (like residuals). However, Mahalanoibis-based QQ plots typically use the chi-squared distribution. Using your `qqPlot2`,  the plots are nearly identical. To render them identically, copy the code from my function for quartiles, to get `a` and `b`. (You need `qz`, & `qx` to get `a` & `b`.) Add to the plot with `geom_abline(intercept = a, slope = b)` (drop the `geom_smooth` call).

Comment: Hi @Kat!
I still haven't been able to reproduce it satisfactorily.
When I use the function thinking about my problem it is showing an error:
````df2 <- gVals(dm, "chisq", .95)
ggplot(df2, aes(x = z, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(df2, aes(intercept = a, slope = b)) +
  annotate("line", x = df2$z, y = df2$uc, color = "red", lty = 2) +
  annotate("line", x = df2$z, y = df2$dc, color = "red", lty = 2)````
Could you update your answer so that the functions and arguments for each graph are separate?

Comment: I have updated my answer; instead of extracting the code, as I suggested, I went one step further and made a few small modifications to the function: I uncommented/commented the quartile/robust line options, and I made it so the output included the slope and intercept of the line of fit.

Comment: Hi Kat!
I apologize again, but, I'm still not succeeding in fully reproducing the mahalanobis vs. quantile distance graph. quantiles I've amended the question so you can see what I'm running into, see the end. Could you post the solution using my problem? In such a way that the envelope is similar?

Comment: You're going to have to include your data in your question. The objects `resmcp` and `dm`. To add these, use the function `dput`, like  `dput(resmcp)` to create reproducible data that you can copy and paste into your post.

Comment: Hi Kat, but the data is in the code.
See this line of code above: ``fit = lme(distance ~ age, method="REML",data = Orthodont)``, that is, using ``Orthodont`` data that is inside the ``nlme`` package. 
Thank you once again for your assistance. I need the graph just like the example using ``qqPlot2``.

Comment: Your code does not work. For example, `Z` i called, but never created in the global environment. (When you create variables in loops and functions, they aren't global variables.)  I did try to troubleshoot. The 304 lines of code that you take from creating `fit` to creating `rescp` were redundant—it's an exact match for the data that's already in the `fit` object: `fit[["residuals"]][, 1]`.  It looks like`dm` is in attempt to recreate `fit[["residuals"]][, 2]` but it is not the same data. Can you please add the data in `dm` to your question? Please use `dput` to make it reproducible.

Comment: Hi Kat, thanks for your help! 
I managed to solve it through the library ``qqplotr``.

``library(qqplotr);
dist <- "chisq";
dpar <- list(df = q);
QT <- data.frame(QUANTIS = dm); ggplot(QT, aes(sample = QUANTIS)) +
  stat_qq_band(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_point(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar) +
  stat_qq_line(distribution = dist, dparams = dpar, color = "blue");
qqPlot2(dm, distribution = 'chisq', df = q, pch = 20,
             ylab = expression(paste("Quantis de Mahalanobis")),
             xlab = "Quantis da Qui-quadrado")``